# how to move these bottom line under scooter in after effects

Tags: after-effects

[image: moving scooter]

I have this lines in illustrator and imported whole art as layers and i want to animate these lines like above animation.is there any other way to make things easy
i had imported ai file as layers and then animated everything. i had tried converting it into shape layers and use trim path but the problem is bottom line has several small lines.